# Swift Try/Catch NSJSONSerialization

Tags: json, swift, try-catch, swift2

I'm running a NSJSONSerialization command with try catches but it is still failing when the command returns a nil. What am I doing incorrect with my try catches?

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` happens at the line where z is set. Why doesn't the catch handle this?

```
    func reachForWebsite(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://myURL")
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        do {
            let z = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as! [NSObject: AnyObject]
        } catch let myJSONError {
            print(myJSONError)
        }
    }
    task!.resume()
}
```

Comment: your `data` object is nil and you are unwrapping it

Comment: If I understand correctly, `do catch` in Swift 2.0 does not catch the exceptions but only Errors that have been thrown by the method in `try` call. That why your code can still crash even you put in a `do catch`. In this case, maybe it's the unwrapping of `data` that cause the crash.

Answer (score 3):

The `do`-`try`-`catch` process catches errors that are thrown, but is not a generalized exception handling process. As before, as a developer, you are still responsible for preventing exceptions from arising (e.g. the forced unwrapping of the optional `NSData`).

So, check to make sure `data` is not `nil` before proceeding. Likewise, don't use `as!` in the cast unless you are assured that the cast cannot fail. It is safer to `guard` against `data` being `nil` and perform an optional binding of the JSON to a dictionary:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { data, response, error in
    guard data != nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    do {
        if let z = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? [String: AnyObject] {
            // do something with z
        }
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: `task` is not optional, it is from type `NSURLSessionDataTask`. you have to call it without `?`

Comment: It once was optional, but no longer. But I've updated answer to reflect current API.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the values of `error` and `data` before trying to give them to `NSJSONSerialization` to parse – `data` is probably nil, which is what triggers your crash.